# Greatest common divisor of polynomial in Finite Field(256), AES

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

Have assigment and will use it as example, found solution computationaly, want to understand idea.

It is about *SubBytes* procedure in AES, particulary about finding inverse of polynomial.

Suppose we have element $A=x^5+1$ in finite field $F=\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1$ and it is required to compute $A^{-1}$, so that $AA^{-1}=1$

Computationally $A^{-1}=x^6 + x^5 + x^3 + x^2 + x$, $AA^{-1}=(x^5+1)(x^6 + x^5 + x^3 + x^2 + x)=x^{11} + x^{10} + x^8 + x^7 + x^5 + x^3 + x^2 + x$

Lets name $I=x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1$ for convenience, it is ideal of $F$. Then $AA^{-1}-I*x^3-I*x^2-I=1$, $AA^{-1}$ reduces to $1$ alright.

Well, how to get $A^{-1}=x^6 + x^5 + x^3 + x^2 + x$? This is where it gets messy for me.

It is my understanding, that $A^{-1}$ is found by eucleidean algorithm, in this case $(x^5+1)*A^{-1}+I*R=1$, where $R \in F$.

What I do.. try to do:

$(x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1)=(x^5+1)(x^3)+(x^4 + x + 1)$

$(x^5+1)=(x^4 + x + 1)(x)+(x^2 + x + 1)$
.. it is kinda mess, see work at Cloud Sage[Removed]

What I am doing wrong above, when I try to find `F.xgcd(A)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took a lot of thought, had the right box but was looking in wrong corner.

Will answer myself, for own convenience will change letters a bit.

All coefficients are modulo 2, and it is required to find polynomials $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ so that $A(x)P(x)+B(x)Q(x)=1$, where $A(x)=x^5+1$ and $B(x)=x^8+x^4+x^3+x^1+x^0$. Actually, we need only $P(x)=A^{-1}(x)$

Anyway:

$x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1=(x^5+1)(x^3)+(x^4+x+1)$ [1]
where
$(x^5+1)=(x^4+x+1)(x)+(x^2+x+1)$ [2]
where
$(x^4+x+1)=(x^2+x+1)(x^2+x)+(1)$ [3]
where, well
$(x^2+x+1)=(x^2+x+1)(1)+0$

Lets express $1$ from [3] by what we have in [1], ie
$1=(x^4+x+1)+((x^5+1)+(x^4+x+1)(x))(x^2+x)$
$1=(x^5+1)(x^2+x)+(x^4+x+1)(x^3+x^2+x)$
excellent, now lets substitute $x^4+x+1$ from [1]
$1=(x^5+1)(x^2+x)+((x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1)+(x^5+1)(x^3))(x^3+x^2)=$
$=A(x)(x^6+x^5+x^3+x^2+x)+B(x)(x^3+x^2+1)$

Where $A^{-1}=x^6+x^5+x^3+x^2+x$, which was looked for. $\Box$

Comment: and, of course - polynomials must have 1 as gcd. Kinda implied here

Comment: Looks good to me. If you are planning on doing some coding here, you may want to consider using a few look-up-tables (unless working on tightly memory controlled device). See [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/591253/11619) for small toy examples using the discrete logarithm in performing the field arithmetic. In [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/76045/11619) contains a link to a complete log table of $GF(256)$.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem:

> Suppose we have element $A=x^5+1$ in finite field $F=\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1)$ and it is required to compute $A^{-1}$, so that $AA^{-1}=1$

This means that we are looking for an element $B$ such that : $AB=BA=1$ in $F$, this means in terms of polynomials that there exists $Q$ such that:
$$A(x)B(x)=1+Q(x)\cdot (x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1) $$
And if this identity is satisfied we say that $B$ is the inverse of $A$ and denoted by $B=A^{-1}$ (To see things clearly you can make an analogy with $\mathbb{Z_p}$ and try to find the inverse of an element);

Now, how can we compute the inverse of an element? we use generally the [Extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) and here are some references explaining exactly the same problem:

- [Finding the inverse of an element in finite field](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/505619/204937)
- [How to use the Extended Euclidean Algorithm manually?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85830/how-to-use-the-extended-euclidean-algorithm-manually/85841#85841)
- [Algorithm for computing the inverse of a polynomial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421409/algorithm-for-computing-the-inverse-of-a-polynomial)