# Find the inverse of x^7 + x^6 + x^3 + x + 1 in Rijndael's finite field

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

I managed to calculate the GCD($x^7 + x^6 + x^3 + x + 1$, $x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1$) and I did some steps of the xgcd but I don't know exactly how to 'group' the polynomials.

Field: $F2^8 / m(x)$
$m(x) = x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1$

GCD:

(1) $(x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1)  /  (x^7 + x^6 + x^3 + x + 1)$ -> Quotient = $x+1$ Remainder = $x^6 + x^2 + x$ 
(2) $(x^7 + x^6 + x^3 + x + 1) / (x^6 + x^2 + x)$  -> Quotient = $x+1$ Remainder = $1$

Remainder is 1 so it has inverse. 
Now I want to compute the inverse.

(1) $ 1 = (x^7 + x^6 + x^3 + x + 1) + (x^6+x^2+x)*(x+1)$
(2) $ 1 = (x^7 + x^6 + x^3 + x + 1) + [(x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1) + (x^7 + x^6 + x^3 + x + 1) * (x+1)] * (x+1)$ 
(3) $ 1 = (x^7 + x^6 + x^3 + x + 1) + (x+1)*(x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1) + (x^7 + x^6 + x^3 + x + 1) * (x+1) * (x+1)$ 
(4) ??

 I have one part of the Bezout's identity but I don't know how to continue to get the other.

Comment: You don't tell us what you are trying to do. Presumably, Rijndael's finite field is of characteristic $p,$ for some $p?$ $\mathbb Z_p[x]/q(x)$ for $q(x)$ your $8$th-degree polynomial?

Comment: It looks like, the finite field is [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/505580/find-the-inverse-of-x6x4x1-in-the-finite-field-mathbbz-2x-x8x4?rq=1). This post shows you how to proceed.

Comment: Check out [this old post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/529238/11619) as well.