# Calculate GCD$(x^4+x+1,x^3+x^2)$ and a Bezout Identity in $\mathbb{F_2}$

Tags: polynomials

A really short task:

> Calculate GCD$(x^4+x+1,x^3+x^2)$ and a Bezout Identity in $\mathbb{F_2}.$

I've tried it but my GCD is $1$ and I cannot see where my mistake is.

$x^4+x+1= x \cdot (x^3+x^2) + x^3 +x + 1$

$x^3+x^2 = 1 \cdot (x^3 + x + 1) + x^2 + x + 1$

$x^3+x+1 = x \cdot (x^2 + 1 + x) + x^2 + 1$

$x^2+x+1 = 1 \cdot (x^2+1) + x$

$x^2 + 1 = x \cdot x + 1$

$x = 1 \cdot x + 0$

Comment: Sorry for my incorrect answer (and tone), I was confusing two polynomials. Why do you think your calculation has a mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easy when using the [augmented-matrix form](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242) of the extended Euclidean algorithm.

$\begin{eqnarray}
(1)&&  &&x^4\!+x+1 \,&=&\, \left<\,\color{#c00}1,\color{#0a0}0\,\right>\ \ \ {\rm i.e.}\,\ \ x^4\!+x+1 = \color{#c00}1\cdot (x^4\!+x+1) + \color{#0a0}0\cdot(x^3\!+x^2)\\
(2)&&  && x^3\!+x^2 \,&=&\, \left<\,\color{#c00}0,\color{#0a0}1\,\right>\ \ \ {\rm i.e.}\,\quad\ \ \ x^3\!+x^2 = \color{#c00}0\cdot (x^4\!+x+1) + \color{#0a0}1\cdot(x^3\!+x^2)\\
(3)&=&(1)-x\cdot (2)\quad && x^3\!+x+1 \,&=&\, \left<\,1,\,x\,\right>\\
(4)&=&(2)-(3)\quad  && x^2\!+x+1 \,&=&\, \left<\,1,\,x+1\,\right>\\
(5)&=&(2)-x\cdot(4)\quad &&\qquad\quad\ \ \ x \,&=&\, \left<x,\,x^2+x+1\right>\\
(6)&=&(4)-(x\!+\!1)\,(5)\!\!\!\! &&\qquad\quad\ \ \ 1 \,&=&\, \left<\color{#c00}{x^2+x+1},\ \color{#0a0}{x^3+x}\right>
\end{eqnarray}$

The Bezout Identity is $\ 1\, =\,  (\color{#c00}{x^2\!+x+1})(x^4\!+x+1) + (\color{#0a0}{x^3\!+x})(x^3\!+x^2)$

Comment: [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/124307/242) for another worked example.