# Methods for finding polynomials in Bézout's identity

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need to find (if they exists) $h(x)$ and $k(x)$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that

$20 = h(x) (x^2 +1) + k(x) (x^3 -3)$

my manual does not provide any method to compute the unknown functions, I was suggested to use the Euclidean extended algorithm but since it is not treated in the book I'd prefer not using it.

Comment: Let $h(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, $k(x)=dx+e$, multiply everything out, solve for the unknowns $a,b,c,d,e$ (but Euclid is much easier).

Comment: How have you chosen the definition of h(x) and k(x)?

Comment: I used a good statement of Bezout.

Comment: Note that if you know the Euclidean algorithm, the extended version is obvious:  it only relies an the fact that, not only the g.c.d. satisfies a Bézout's identity,  but *all remainders* in the process do. Other than that, you can start from the last equality in the succession of Euclidean divisions, and go backwards.

Comment: To expand on my comment: if $h,k$ is a solution, and $p$ is any polynomial, then $h-(x^3-3)p,k+(x^2+1)p$ is also a solution, and then you can choose $p$ so that $h-(x^3-3)p$ has degree two (by taking $p$ to be the quotient on division of $h$ by $x^3-3$), and then automatically (by considering the degrees) $k+(x^2+1)p$ will have degree one. Try it!

Comment: You have several answers now, gioretikto. Any thoughts about any of them?

Comment: It's not polite to ask people for help and then, when they help you, to run away and hide. Please engage with us, gioretikto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\!\!\bmod\,\overbrace{ x^2+1}^{\color{#c00}{\textstyle \!\!x^2\!\equiv\! -1}\!\!\!}\!:\,\ {-}20 \equiv (\overbrace{3-x\color{#c00}{x^2}}^{\!\!\!\!\!\textstyle 3+x})\,k$ $\iff k \equiv\dfrac{-20^{\phantom{|^|}}}{x+3} \equiv -20\left[ \dfrac{x\, -\, 3}{\smash{\underbrace{\color{#c00}{x^2}-9}_{\large\!\!\! -10}}}\right] \equiv 2(x-3)$

**Remark** $ $ If mod arithmetic is unfamiliar we can do the same by evaluating the hypothesized Bezout equation  $\, 20 = k(x) (x^2-3) + h(x) (x^2+1)\,$  at $\,x = i^{\phantom{|^|}}\!\!,\,$ yielding

$$20 = k(i)(-i-3)\iff k(i) = \dfrac{\!\!-20}{i+3} = 2(i-3)\ \ \rm as\ above\quad $$

By [theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3274043/242) we know there is a solution with $\,\deg k < \deg(x^2+2),\,$ so $\,k = ax+b,\,$ so $\, 2i-6 = k(i) = ai+b \iff (2-a)i = b+6\iff a=2,\, b=-6,\,$ by $\,i\not\in \Bbb Q$

Comment: **Remark** $ $ Since $\Bbb Q[x]/(x^2+1)\cong \Bbb Q[i]\,$ we are essentially calculating with $\,x\,$ as  $\,i,\, $ so the calculation can be viewed as Gaussian integer arithmetic if we replace $\,x\,$ by $\,i\ \ $

Comment: **Alternatively** apply the Extended Euclidean Algorithm as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/124307/242) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/637565/242) (they explain the general idea behind the method in Bernard's answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use the *extended Euclidean algorithm* (same as for $\mathbf Z$):

\begin{array}{r| c c l}
r(x)&u(x)&v(x) & q(x) \\ \hline
x^3-3 & 0 & 1 \\
x^2+1& 1 & 0 & x \\ \hline
-x-3 & -x & 1 & -x+3 \\
10  &1+3x-x^2 & x-3 \\ \hline 
\end{array}
Therefore, one obtains
$$ 10 =(1+3x-x^2)(x^2+1) +(x -3)(x^3-3)$$
whence   $\quad 20=2(1+3x-x^2)(x^2+1)+2 (x-3)(x^3-3)$.

Comment: But OP doesn't want to use Euclid.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I didn't know that when I posted. The O.P.$ was not edited yet  (or I misread).

Answer (score 0):

Just to show that it can be done: $$20=(x^2+1)(ax^2+bx+c)+(x^3-3)(dx+e)$$ $$=(a+d)x^4+(b+e)x^3+(a+c)x^2+(b-3d)x+c-3e$$ so $$a+d=0, b+e=0, a+c=0, b-3d=0,c-3e=20$$ so $$b=3d,e=-b=-3d,c=-a=d,20=c-3e=d+9d=10d$$ hence $$d=2,b=6,e=-6,c=2,a=-2$$ and we have $$h(x)=-2x^2+6x+2,k(x)=2x-6$$