# If $u$ is algebraic over $\mathbb Q$, then the span of $\{1, u, u^2, ..., u^{n-1}\}$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

**Problem:** If $u\in \mathbb C$ is algebraic over $\mathbb Q$, then the span of $\{1, u, u^2, ..., u^{n-1}\}$ is a field.

**Attempt:**  Since every element in the span is in $\mathbb C$ it suffices to show that we have a subfield of $\mathbb C$. Closure under addition and multiplication is clear to me.  It's also clear that every element in the span has an additive inverse; namely, it's negative.  But showing that every nonzero linear combination has a multiplicative inverse is throwing me off.

**Question:**  Suppose $f(u)$ belongs to the span. Then $f(u) = a_0 + a_1u + \cdots + a_{n-1}u^{n-1}$ where the coefficients are rational numbers.  What would the inverse look like or how would I construct it?

Comment: It depends what tools you can use. The standard way is to define the homomorphism $\varphi:\mathbb{Q}[x]\to\mathbb{C}$ by $\varphi(f)=f(u)$. The image is exactly your span, which is usually denoted by $\mathbb{Q}[u]$. The kernel is generated by the minimal polynomial of $u$, call it $m(x)$. (you should have noted in your question that $n=\deg(m)$) Then $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(m)\cong\mathbb{Q}[u]$. Since the minimal polynomial is irreducible, this quotient ring is a field.

Comment: It is difficult to construct the inverse directly. A non-constructive argument begins as follows: let $\psi_{f(u)}$ be the map $K \to K, x \mapsto xf(u)$, where $K$ is the span over $\mathbb{Q}$. Can you see how this might lead to solution?

Comment: An alternative is to use the fact that [a finite dimensional integral domain is a field](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/63950/11619).

Comment: BTW, this is a duplicate (in all the different ways). I want input from others before I vote to close as a duplicate, because my vote would be immediately binding (dupehammer), and the choice of the target is not easy (though we can use all of them).

Comment: @Mark "Since the minimal polynomial is irreducible, this quotient ring is a field" - This result I don't have.  This is a linear algebra course, believe it or not.

Comment: @legionwhale No, I don't quite see it.  Show that the map is a bijection maybe?  Or injection is enough since it's a map to itself.

Comment: @UngarLinski Yes, show it is an injection is sufficient, but only because it's a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$. dxiv has probably given the nicest answer actually.

Comment: @legionwhale It is not hard to explicitly construct an inverse see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1363867/789929

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku True. I forgot that the construction there works for arbitrary elements.

Comment: See the linked dupes (and their links) for all the common arguments, Please delete this question since we already have too many copies of these arguments, which makes it difficult to locate the best answers by search. You will need to unaccept the answer before deleting (click the checkmark).

Comment: @BillDubuque This question is significantly narrower in scope than the ones you linked as duplicates. Just because it's a (very) particular case of the general result doesn't make it a dupe IMHO.

Comment: @dxiv It si not  really "narrower". But even if you think so, see [abstract duplicates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1756/242). Your answer (and likely any other) is dupe of hundreds of others and only serves to clutter searxch results on this huge FAQ, making it difficult (if not impossible) for users to locate the "best" answers by search.

Comment: @BillDubuque I laid no claim it was original research ;-) But, in the context of the narrow question here, it is an elementary and constructive answer, which btw I do not see as such in the dupes you linked, on a cursory look.

Comment: @dxiv You ddin't read carefully them, since links to constructive methods for inversion such as using the extended Euclidean algorithm to compute the Bezout equation are already in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/100201/242) in one of the dupes, along with linked woirked examples.  We have *many huindreds* of posts on that as you should surely know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a constructive proof, let $p(x)$ be the $n^{th}$ degree rational polynomial having $u$ as a root. It can be assumed WLOG that $p(x)$ is irreducible, so either $f(x)$ is a rational multiple of $p(x)$ or otherwise $\gcd(p(x),f(x))=1$. The former case means $f(u)=0$ which is not invertible, in the latter case by Bezout's lemma ([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3274038/how-do-i-prove-b%c3%a9zouts-identity-of-polynomials-in-fx), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3140242/how-does-the-extended-euclidean-algorithm-generalize-to-polynomials), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3823266/methods-for-finding-polynomials-in-b%C3%A9zouts-identity), [4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity_and_extended_GCD_algorithm)) there exist rational polynomials $a(x),b(x)$ such that $a(x)f(x)+b(x)p(x)$ $=\gcd(p(x),f(x))=1$. Setting $x=u$ gives $\require{cancel}a(u)f(u)+\cancel{b(u)p(u)}=1$ which both proves the existence of and explicitly calculates the inverse $\big(f(u)\big)^{-1}=a(u)$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).  This already occurs here many tens (if not hundreds) of times already.

Comment: Bezout is not needed since we get an inverse immediately by rearranging the equation $p(u)=0$ - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/100201/242). @OP see the linked dupes for more *conceptual* answers that will help you better understand the essence of the matter.

Comment: @BillDubuque With the notation from the linked post, finding $\,\rm f(x)\,$ is not trivial. This is why I started my answer here with "*for a constructive proof*". It proves the inverse exists *and* it calculates it, using nothing more than euclidean division.

Comment: @BillDubuque It's a different $f$ there. *Your* $f(x)$ would be the rational polynomial that *OP's* $f(u)$ satisfies.

Comment: My first comment needs only the *existence* of  $p(x)$ with $p(\alpha) = 0,\ \alpha = f(u)\,$ (immediate by fin. dim). In any case, both the common existential *and* constructive methods are already in the dupes and their links (and in *hundreds* of other answers). Their is no need to repeat them *ad infintum* (doing so clutters search results so greatly that people give up searching for answers - meaning all of our work over the past $13$ years is mostly  for nought),

Comment: @BillDubuque FWIW my first comment here was in reply to the "*Bezout is not needed*" part. As I wrote, the reason Bezout _was_ used here is because my answer set out to provide a *constructive* proof. I am well aware that proving the existence does not *require* constructing the inverse. But there is nothing wrong with a constructive proof, either. I know similar proofs must have been posted before. But for someone less versed, it can be easier to understand a 5-line self-contained proof, rather than follow links 2-3 levels deep. We can agree to disagree, of course, and I'll leave it at that.

Comment: Imo it is *much* better (as in [this linked dupe](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100195/division-of-complex-and-algebraic-numbers-by-rationalizing-the-denominator))  to give a few *onsite* links (including links to worked examples) than to give a single *offsite* (Wikipeda) link as you do. The linked Wikipedia section is *very poor* pedagogically and will ony serve to obfuscate the essence of the matter. Otoh, the linked dupes are much more helpful pedagogically.  We should aim to maximize pedagogical quality, not minimize #clicks.