# Polynomial modular inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, algorithms, modular-arithmetic, inverse

I am trying to understand the modular inverse of a polynomial. Let $A , Q$ be polynomials; what is the polynomial $B$ such that $A B = 1 \pmod Q$?

I tried searching articles from [Finding inverse of polynomial in a field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124300/finding-inverse-of-polynomial-in-a-field) and http://people.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~csaha/lectures/lec5.pdf but could not find enough.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: sorry , unable to disply single quote .
A(x) * Q(x) = 1 mod (P(x)).

given A(x) and P(x).

want to find Q(x)..

thank u

Comment: link to lec5.pdf is dead

Answer (score 1):

You need to find $U$ and $V$ polynomial over your field such that :

$$A(x)U(x)+Q(x)V(x)=1 $$

This is the Bezout Identity for polynomials over $F[x]$ (here $F$ is the base field you are implicitely working with).

Such $U$ and $V$ exists if and only if $gcd(A,Q)=1$ if and only if $A$ is invertible modulo $Q$. Now take $A$ invertible mod $Q$ by what is written before there exists $U$ and $V$ such that :

$$A(x)U(x)+Q(x)V(x)=1 $$

Hence if you look at this equation mod $Q$ it gives $AU=1$ mod $Q$. So the inverse you are looking for is the polynomial $U$ in the Bezout identity.

Last question "how to compute a Bezout identity"? It is just making an extended Eculidean algorithm... see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor

Comment: thank u 
I am trying to use this in Fast fourier transform . so could give me some intuition about how to use the concept in FFT or any related links