# GCD of polynomials over GF(2)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, gcd-and-lcm

I have two polynomials:

$$f(x)=x^5+x^3+x+1\\ g(x)=x^4+x^3+x+1.$$

I have to find out $\gcd(f,g)$ over $\operatorname{GF}(2).$

I think the gcd is: $x+1.$ But I am not sure, because here is the remainder $x^2+1.$

Another problem is to find out polynomials $a(x)$ and $b(x),$ like $$\gcd(f(x),g(x))= a(x)f(x)+b(x)g(x).$$ Maybe I can use Extended Euclid's algorithm, but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: The Extended Euclid's algorithm is explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). Following gives you both answers.

Comment: The first remainder should be $x^2+x.$ $$f(x)=(x+1)g(x)+(x^2+x)$$

Comment: First $x^5+x^3+x+1=(x+1)(x^4+x^3+x+1)+(x^2+x)$. Next $x^4+x^3+x+1=x^2(x^2+x)+(x+1)$. Next $x^2+x=x(x+1)+0$. Therefore, as you said $x+1$ is the GCD. Now you can substitute the first equation into the second to get $x^4+x^3+x+1=x^2[(x^5+x^2+x+1)-(x+1)(x^4+x^3+x+1)]+(x+1)$. Reorganizing you get the Bezout equation $x+1=x^2(x^5+x^3+x+1)+(x^3+x^2+1)(x^4+x^3+x+1)$

Answer (score 0):

Note that$$x^5+x^3+x+1=(x^4+x^3+x+1)(x+1)+x^2+x,$$that$$x^4+x^3+x+1=(x^2+x)x^2+x+1,\tag1$$and that$$x^2+1=(x+1)x.$$The remainder of this final polynomial division is $0$ and therefore$$\gcd(x^5+x^3+x+1,x^4+x^3+x+1)=x+1$$since $x+1$ is the remainder of the division $(1)$ (that is, it is the last non-null remainder).

Answer (score -1):

It's easy: $\,(f,g) = (f\!-\!g,g) = (\color{#c00}x^4(x\!-\!1),g)=\bbox[5px,border:1px solid #0a0]{x\!-\!1}\,$ by $\,\color{#c00}x\nmid g;\,\ x\!-\!1\mid g\,$ by $\,g(1)=0$

---

For part two, to find the gcd Bezout identity it suffices to solve

$$\begin{align} c\, (f-g)\ +\ b\, g &\,=\, x\!+\!1\,\  (=x\!-\!1)\\[.2em]
\iff\   c x^4(x\!+\!1) + b (1\!+\!x^3) (x\!+\!1) &\,=\, x\!+\!1\\[.2em]
\iff\  c\, x^4 + b\, (1\!+\!x^3) &\,=\, 1\ \ {\rm via\ cancel}\,\ x\!+\!1\end{align}$$

By inspection an obvious choice is $\, b = 1\!-\!x^3,\ c =\color{#0a0}{x^2}.\,$ Or, by [Gauss's algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242)

$\bmod\, \color{#c00}{1+x^3}\!:\ \ c\equiv \dfrac{1}{x(\color{#c00}{x^3})}\equiv \dfrac{1}{x(\color{#c00}{-1})}\equiv \dfrac{x^2}{-\color{#c00}{x^3}}\equiv \dfrac{\color{#0a0}{x^2}}{\color{#c00}1}$

If you wish to *mechanically* apply the extended Euclidean algorithm (vs. above optimizations thereof) then it is most convenient to use the *forward* form [described here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/124307/242) The vulgar *backward* form is far more cumbersome and error prone.